# Расскажите пожалуйста, как построить схему парсинга веб-страниц? Вижу $curl = curl_init();

Tags: php

Вижу пример:

```
$curl = curl_init();
...
$data = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($data);
```

Писать могу, разберусь. Я так понимаю это php. Но как построить схему? Наверное надо запустить типа серверного приложения, которое будет выполнять постоянный вызов, для дальнейшей обработки данных (разбирать страницу хочу каждую секунду).
Пробовал вариант с хром-расширением. Все четко работает (выбирает нужные данные и отправляет мне на домен в мой php, который заполняет мою базу mysql), но когда открыто 5-10 страниц. Как открываю 20-30-40, все, капец, хром сам не успевает даже просто отражать эти страницы - зависает наглухо. Мозиловский SLIMER JS наверное так же поведет себя, т.к. открывает окно свое на каждую страницу. Поэтому думаю должно быть что-то типа Node?!

Comment: Какую схему? Что вы собрались парсить?

Comment: Веб страница, данные на ней меняются. Само парсингье работает как надо. В хром-расширении на js написал. Данные идут. Но он (chrome) не тянет на большом количестве страниц . Схему прошу: с помощью чего построить, чтоб с указанных веб-страниц получать html каждую секунду. Например php-скрипт. Но их знаю как запускать со свое странице, на моем веб-сервере. А в данном случае постоянное его выполнение необходимо

Comment: если линукс, то cron. Если винда, то можно попробовать react php.

Comment: Перефразирую:  1) получить html-код с нужного url.  2) разобрать и получить нужные данные.  3) отправить на мой домен эти данные в бд.   2 и 3 реализовано и работает как надо. А вот нюанс с п.1. Что разворачивать и на чем писать, чтоб парсить паралельно страниц 100, каждую 1-2сек?

Comment: pthreads, если вам ближе php. А так - на любом языке поддерживающий многопоточность

Comment: Ближе мне 1с)), но знаком dephi, java, c, php, js. Так как запускать этот PHP-скрипт на постоянной основе. Могу с сайта только, но он там одноразовый же, по обращению. А нужно в постоянном действии чтоб работал - о такой схеме прошу помощи, на пальцах чтоб)

Comment: @dnikitin, php вполне самостоятельный язык, почему вы решили что только с сайта? Можете запустить программу в бесконечном цикле на сервере , или настроить запуск скрипта по расписанию. Мне кажется что web сервер вам и не нужно поднимать.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет php-библиотека `simple_html_dom`

Запускаете локальный сервер (DenWer, OpenServer, ...), создаёте сайт, подключаете библиотеку и парсите нужный сайт.

На [сайте библиотеки](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) хорошая документация о том как с ней работать.